# expected value of win

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expectation

Hey I have got a problem with this exercise:
probability of win p=0.5. Ticket cost 2. Prize for winners 4. Tom bought 8 tickets. What is an expected value of win?

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "house advantage" here.  If Tom were to purchase a very large amount of tickets, he would win 2 half the time, and lose 2 half the time almost exactly, so the expected value of the game is zero. Tom will not win anything, or lose anything should he buy *many* tickets.  The purchase of only eight tickets, does not change the nature of the game or expected value, but that does not guarantee half of those eight tickets will win; eight is just too small a number. The expected value of a win is actually one (0,5)(2).  But a loss is negative one, (0.5)(-2)  To find the expected value, you add these two numbers together, which in this case is zero.